# UIView and it's subview not responding to touches

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uipickerview

I've placed a UIPickerView inside a UIView. The picker was working fine before I did this, but it is now no longer responding to touches. It appears the touches are going straight through the UIView and the UIPickerView subview, as I am able to scroll the background still.

I'm setting up my view and the PickerView subview like this, called from viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)setupMapClusterPicker {

UIView *pickerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
pickerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
[pickerView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];


_mapClusterPicker = [UIPickerView new];

_mapClusterPicker.delegate = self;
_mapClusterPicker.dataSource = self;
_mapClusterPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
_mapClusterPicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


_mapClusterPicker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

_mapClusterPicker.hidden = YES;

[pickerView addSubview:_mapClusterPicker];

[self.view addSubview:pickerView];



[pickerView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
[pickerView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.widthAnchor].active = YES;

[_mapClusterPicker.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:pickerView.bottomAnchor].active = YES;

[_mapClusterPicker.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:pickerView.widthAnchor].active = YES;
}
```

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Examine with the view debugger. Odds on something in the hierarchy having a height or width of 0.

Comment: I believe UserInteraction is disabled of Parent UIView